# Deploying a custom build of Datalab to Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

For a project we are trying to expand Google Cloud Datalab and deploy the modified version to the Google Cloud platform. As I understand it, the deploying process normally consists of the following steps:

1. Build the Docker image
2. Push it to the Container Registry
3. Use the `container` parameter with the Google Cloud deployer to specify the correct Docker image, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/getting-started).

Since the default container registry, i.e. `gcr.io/cloud_datalab/datalab:<tag>` is off-limits for non-Datalab contributors, we pushed the Docker image to our own container registry, i.e. to `gcr.io/<project_id>/datalab:<tag>`.

However, the Google Cloud deployer only pulls directly from `gcr.io/cloud_datalab/datalab:<tag>` (with the tag specified by the `container`parameter) and does not seem to allow specification of the source container registry. The deployer does not appear to be open-source, leaving us with no way to deploy our image to Google Cloud.

We have looked into creating a custom deployment similar to the example listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/step-by-step-guide/create-container-deployment) but this never starts Datalab, so we suspect the start script is more complicated.

**Question**: How can we deploy a Datalab image from our own container registry to Google Cloud?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deployment parameters can be guessed but it is easier to get the Google Cloud Datalab deployment script by `ssh`ing to the temporary compute node that is responsible for deployment and browsing the `/datalab` folder. This contains a runtime configuration file for use with the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/how-to). Using this configuration file, the `google preview app deploy` command (which accepts an `--image` parameter for Docker images) will deploy this to the App Engine correctly.